# My Vscode seems to be buggy after the new update

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode automatically updated on it's own 2 days ago, and ever since then it has become laggy and buggy. There seems to be a delay when moving the cursor from point A to point B or even when typing characters, or even running the project in the emulator. At first, I thought it was my Laptop's issue, but then all the other software and programs were working fine. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode but still the problem persists. I tried disabling all the extensions but still the bug remains intact. Does anyone have any solutions for this problem?

This is taken from the about section of VSCode:

```
Version: 1.45.0 (user setup)
Commit: d69a79b73808559a91206d73d7717ff5f798f23c
Date: 2020-05-07T16:18:48.860Z
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Comment: I guess would be rather related to your Graphic Driver, rather than VSCode, or some integration there ...

Comment: Update your video drivers. If that doesn't help, report the bug too the VSCode development team.

Comment: most of Microsoft products are buggy. They are good at creating bugs for millions of users. try reinstalling your vs code